# Do sets in a topological space satisfying the $T_1$ axiom need to have infinitely many points?

Tags: general-topology

I'm taking my first topology course and we are going through Munkres. We just recently began studying Hausdorff spaces and the $T_1$ axiom. I had a question which might be quite simple about theorem $17.9$.

**Theorem 17.9**: Let X be a topological space satisfying the $T_1$ axiom. Let $A \subseteq X$. The point $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$.

*Just a reminder that Munkres defines a neighborhood $U$ of a point $x$ to be an open set that contains $x$.*

Now the proof to show the forward direction supposes that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ which has a neighborhood $U$ which intersects $A$ in only finitely many points and then derive a contradiction to the definition of limit point.

The proof makes sense and I don't have many qualms there, but I was wondering, how do we know that $A$ has infinitely many points to begin with? Obviously we don't actually need to care when carrying out the logic of the proof because we just make assumptions and contradict them and see what happens, but I guess I was curious about what this meant about the type of spaces that satisfy the $T_1$ axiom. Does this mean that sets $B$ consisting of finitely many points to begin with can't have topologies defined on them that satisfy the $T_1$ axiom?

Comment: If $A$ is finite, this theorem shows that $A$ has no limit points. You don't know whether $A$ is finite, but the proof is the same, either way.

Comment: Sets $B$ consisting of finitely many points just don't have limit points. Every set can be given the discrete topology to make it $T_1$.

Comment: In other words, every finite subset of a $T_1$ space is closed, and any finite $T_1$ space is discrete.